# Form-based reports generation

Tags: forms, report, reporting

Is there a reporting engine or component (ideally, open source) that will allow the following:

1. Let me build forms
2. When form is opened, it is pre-populated with data previously submitted via this form
3. When a form is filled and submitted that data remains logged somewhere in BD or files
4. Generate a PDF/PPT file based on submitted data (ideally, be able to generate multiple ones based on bindings - for instance, detailed ones and ones with less data in them)
5. (very optional) provide means to view historical data submitted

Comment: if #1 does not mean to create forms graphically, does not look like something really hard to code. (with iReport)

Comment: @Leo, I guess I just don't quite understand how Jasper stuff works (if you are referring to that iReport). I figured they have a report designer and component/server to populate these designed reports with data from various sources (DB, XML and so on) but I don't see where the form population (manual data enty) thing is and how it works.

Comment: iReport can only help you making the reports. Sorry, I meant that you code it using iReport (not only iReport)

Comment: 1, 2, 3 and 5 are not really too hard to program, but your question is very broad, do you want to use an specific language or technology? are you looking something open source or closed source (or you don't mind)? is it desktop, mobile or web based?